# Ubuntu 22.04 completely freezes after a black screen blink

Tags: 22.04, freeze

I'm using Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS, do nothing special, few windows is opened, and all of a sudden the cursor and everything freezes, after that the screen blinks once in black for a second, and after that everything freezes, cursor, windows, everything. I only can press the power button to completely shut it down. I had never experienced like this before.

I also tried in different display ways (Ubuntu on Xorg, Wayland, also installed Cinnamon), always this same error.
Also tried with Ubuntu 22.10, with the same error.

Is anyone knows why it is happening?

I use dual boot with Windows 11 and Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS.
My firmware is up to date, at least there was no update on the Asus site.

And about my Asus Laptop:

```
AMD Ryzen 7 4800H
GeForce GTX 1660Ti
32 GB RAM
```

Comment: Did you install Nvidia drivers?

Comment: I just changed to "Using NVIDIA driver (open kernel) metapackage from nvidia-driver-525-open (proproetary, tested)" in Software & Update. And I'll see if this is fixes the error. Thank you!

Comment: Sadly neither of this fixed the issue.I switched driver in Software & Update, also tried what the other question says, not fixed the issue.

Comment: Lenovo t14s, Ubuntu 22.4.2. the same experience. I just start to google the problem. With i3 the freezes seems to stop.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. To solve it I just upgraded my kernel to the latest stable version (6.2 at the time of writing this). This worked for me, I hope it will also work for you !

Answer (score 0):

I also, had the same problem, after just installing 22.04 LTS Ubuntu. I fixed it by updating the kernel to the latest version (6.2.8).

Comment: Not really an answer as there is no such kernel  called latest kernel. The exact kernel number is required.

Comment: @Bartho1omay Can you please write the exact kernel version number that you updated to?