# Software Updater not working, after upgrading to Linux kernel 6.6.7

Tags: kernel, 22.04

I use Ubuntu 22.04.03 LTS on a Lenovo Ideapad 1 15AMN7.
 I dont' have a dual boot. The sole O.S. in my machine is Ubuntu and had an issue with daily black-freezing-screen for some seconds.

The CPU with the integrated GPU is: AMD Ryzen 3 7320U with Radeon Graphics 1 physical processor; 4 cores; 8 threads
As the HardInfo 0.6-alpha shows me. I have also run the GPU Drawing with success.

I have disabled the Google Chrome's "Use Harware Acceleration" option, because I though it was merely a YouTube problem as I have read in an respective article.

Then the problem insisted, so I followed [this link's instructions](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1457086/ubuntu-22-04-completely-freezes-after-a-black-screen-blink) which is advocating the solution of upgrading the Linux kernel to solve the problem.
But now, I can't upgrade neither from the terminal nor from the Software Updater.

The error message the Soft.Upd. gives me is the following:

**Not all updates can be installed**
Run a partial upgrade, to install as many updates as possible.

This can be caused by:
* A previous upgrade which didn't copmlete
* Problems with some of the installed software
* Unofficial software packages not provided by Ubuntu
* Normal changes of a pre-release version of Ubuntu

If I hit "Partial Upgrade", the Updater steps me to a point that I have to unistall the
"linux-headers-6.6.7-060607-generic-Linux kernel headers for version 6.6.7 on 64bit x86 SMP".

What should I do?

P.S: Well, I don't know if [this site](https://www.kernel.org/) is trustworthy, but it says that the latest stable linux kernel is 6.6.7 with a release date of 2023-12-13.

What I did, was to follow the [instructions on this post!](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1388115/how-do-i-update-my-kernel-to-the-latest-one) ONLY in the paragraph titled "Installing the latest kernel".

Comment: Don't do a partial upgrade. Resolve the issues first.

Comment: Thanks for take latter advice. I have added a post script in my question, hope it makes things more clear!

Comment: The kernel builds you are installing are unsupported. I have added a note to the linked post indicating as such.

Comment: So i guess that I have to downgrade or reinstall the previous kernel version!

Comment: That guess would be correct.

Comment: Thank you all. I did it and it works, at least for now!